# Probability Density Function of non decreasing function

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, random-variables

Can anyone please help me with this random variable question I've stumbled across.

Recall from calculus that a function $h$ is called non-decreasing if $x\leq y$ implies $h(x)\leq h(y)$, for every $x,y \in \textrm{dom}(h)$.

Q1a) Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f$. Prove that the probability distribution function of $X$. i.e. $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy$, is a non decreasing function of $x$ that belongs to $R$.

Q1b) Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$ and  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=1$, and explain the probabilistic meaning of these facts

Comment: First, use MathJax! The integral in Q1a is barely legible. Second, Q1a should read "Prove that the *cumulative distribution function* of $X$...".

Comment: You fixed only half my complaints. That $F(x)$ in Q1a is *not* the probability density function of $X$, it's the CDF!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint for Q1a**: The cumulative distribution function (CDF), *by definition*, has the property that $P(X \leq x) = F(X)$. So you'll have to ponder whether it's possible that for $x_1 \leq x_2$, $P(X \leq x_1) > P(X \leq x_2)$. What would that mean for the probability $P(x_1 < X \leq x_2)$?

**Hint for Q1b**: If $X$ is a real random variable, what is $P(X \in \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Just need to show what it means for the probability P you state at the end of q1a.

Comment: Do you understand what the difference is between a probability density function and a cumulative distribution function?